# Returning or echoing a value from a helper function is giving the value plus a "null" PHP

Tags: php, laravel

I currently have a helper function I have created to calculate a product price by checking an .xlxs price file which has 2 columns, A for numbers of days and B for price for that row.

Now, this all works fine on my quote page which shows the price, however when I run the check again when processing the payment to make sure the price is correct I get a different value returned. Exactly the same data is going in to the exact same helper function.

The response for example on my product display page will show the price value as  "40" for example. But when I call it on my BookingController (using laravel) I get "40" and then another below it that simply says "null". This is stopping me from being able to calculate a price to convert to cents/pence to use with stripe as it says invalid positive integer.

I've done some debugging and when I dd the $price in the helper function it returns just the "40" but when I dd on the variable in the controller is shows the invalid one with the price and "null" below it.

Any ideas whats going on here?

I've tried returning the value in the helper function, and I've also tried echoing it and printing it, all the same issue. I'll show you my code now:

```
$price2 = (new \App\Price\GeneratePrice($duration, $base_price))->calculate();
```

This is the helper function

```
 public function calculate()
{
    $pricelist = '/public/pricelist.xlsx';

    \Excel::load($pricelist, function ($reader) {

       $days = $this->duration;
        $base = $this->basePrice;

        $array = $reader->select(array('days', 'price'))->toArray();
        $size = sizeof($array);
        if ($days > $size) {
            $key = array_search($size, array_column($array, 'days'));
            $diff = $this->duration - $size;
            $k = $array[$key]['price'];
            $baseprice = $base * $diff;
            $price = $k + $baseprice;

            echo $price;
        }
        else {

            $key = array_search($days, array_column($array, 'days'));
            $k = $array[$key]['price'];
            $price = $k;

            echo $price;

        }

    });
}
```

and this is the response I get

```
38
```

"NULL"

Comment: Your "NULL" probably means you left an `echo` or `var_dump` somewhere while testing something. That's usually the reason for having more than one output, when you only expected one.

Comment: I have checked and can't find anything

Comment: I've figured out that the "null" is referring to not returning a value from after the Excel::load. Can't figure out how to get it to return the price in there

Comment: I've figured it out. I wasn't returning it. I made $price = $this->price which is in the constructor, and returned $this->price; All works. Its amazing what you can figure out when you keep trying :D

Comment: Good job! Always nice to see somebody actively trying to solve a problem instead of waiting for others to do the dirty work for them.